# Printing variables in Python 3.4

Tags: python, variables, printing, syntax

So the syntax seems to have changed from what I learned in Python 2... here is what I have so far

```
for key in word:
    i = 1
    if i < 6:
        print ( "%s. %s appears %s times.") % (str(i), key, str(wordBank[key]))
```

The first value being an int, the second a string, and the final an int.

How can I alter my print statement so that it prints the variables correctly?

Comment: `print()` is a function in Python 3, not a statement. Surround everything in your last line (except the word `print`) in parentheses and you'll be all set.

Comment: @CMac: no, you are not. You did this: `print(....)`, which will return `None`, then `None % (one, two, three_strings)`. You want the `something % (one, two, three_strings)` to be done *inside* the `print(....)` call.

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) for future reference...

Comment: here is a good link: https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/string_formatting.html

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The syntax has changed in that [`print` is now a function](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function).  This means that the `%` formatting needs to be done inside the parenthesis:<sup>1</sup>

```
print("%d. %s appears %d times." % (i, key, wordBank[key]))
```

However, since you are using Python 3.x., you should actually be using the newer [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method:

```
print("{}. {} appears {} times.".format(i, key, wordBank[key]))
```

Though `%` formatting is not *officially* deprecated (yet), it is discouraged in favor of `str.format` and will most likely be removed from the language in a coming version (Python 4 maybe?).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Just a minor note: `%d` is the format specifier for integers, not `%s`.</sub>

Comment: The very clunky pre-Python 3.6 syntax has now been superseded with [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html), as per [wwii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48870661/202229). Could you please update your answer, it's obsolete?

Answer (score 61):

Version 3.6+: Use a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals), *f-string* for short

```
print(f"{i}. {key} appears {wordBank[key]} times.")
```

Answer (score 9):

Try the format syntax:

```
print ("{0}. {1} appears {2} times.".format(1, 'b', 3.1415))
```

Outputs:

```
1. b appears 3.1415 times.
```

The print function is called just like any other function, with parenthesis around all its arguments.

Answer (score 6):

You can also format the string like so:

```
>>> print ("{index}. {word} appears {count} times".format(index=1, word='Hello', count=42))
```

Which outputs

```
1. Hello appears 42 times.
```

Because the values are named, their order does not matter. Making the example below output the same as the above example.

```
>>> print ("{index}. {word} appears {count} times".format(count=42, index=1, word='Hello'))
```

Formatting string this way allows you to do this.

```
>>> data = {'count':42, 'index':1, 'word':'Hello'}
>>> print ("{index}. {word} appears {count} times.".format(**data))
1. Hello appears 42 times.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be a mis-placed `)`. In your sample you have the `%` outside of the `print()`, you should move it inside:

Use this:

```
print("%s. %s appears %s times." % (str(i), key, str(wordBank[key])))
```

Answer (score 0):

one can print values using the format method in python. This small example will help 
take input of two numbers a and b. Print a+b in first line and a-b in second line

```
print('{:d}\n{:d}'.format(a+b,a-b))
```

Similarly in the answer we can do

```
print ("{0}. {1} appears {2} times.".format(22, 'c', 9999))
```

The python method format() for string is used to specify a string format. So {0},{1},{2} are like array indexes called as positional parameters. Therefore {0} is assigned first value written in format (a+b), {1} is assigned the second value (a-b) and so on. We can also use keyword instead of positional parameter like for example

```
print("Hi! my name is {name}".format(name="rashi"))
```

Therefore name here is the keyword and its value is Rashi
Hope it helps :)