# Python Syntax error ("")

Tags: python

Here is my code for my program but I'm having problems with a syntax error I cant figure out what the problem is. The Error I'm getting is in `print "employee / supervisor id :" ,k.get_id()," Date joined :" ,k.get_date()`The Syntax error has to do with the "" in that line of code.

```
  `import datetime #this will import the formatting for date and tiem

class employee:

"""docstring for employee"""

def __init__(self, empid,loc,enttime):  

    self.empid = empid

    self.enttime = enttime

    self.exitime = None

    self.date = None

    self.loc = loc

def exittime(self,exitime):

    self.exitime = exitime

def setdate(self,date):

    self.date = date

def get_id(self):

    return self.empid

def get_date(self):

    return self.date

class supervisor(object):

"""docstring for supervisor"""

def __init__(self, supid,loc,enttime):

    self.supid = supid

    self.deptid =loc

    self.enttime =enttime

    self.exitime =None

    self.date = None

def exittime(self,exitime):

    self.exitime = exitime

def setdate(self,date):

    self.date = date

def get_id(self):

    return self.supid

def get_date(self):

    return self.date

def printbydate(l):

    l.sort(key=lambda x: x.date, reverse=True)

    for k in l:
        print "employee / supervisor id :" ,k.get_id()," Date joined :" ,k.get_date()

date1 = datetime.date(2015, 11, 20)

date2 = datetime.date(2017, 11, 27)
a = employee("e112","abc",12)
b = supervisor("s341","abc",14)
a.setdate(date1)
b.setdate(date2)
a.exittime(19)
b.exittime(19)
pil =[]

pil.append(a)
pil.append(b)
printbydate(pil)'
```

Comment: What exactly is the error, and what Python version are you using?

Comment: You also have a tailing quotation on your last line: `printbydate(pil)'`. Paste the error you get exactly.

Comment: Also all methods trailing the class def should be tabbed correctly

Comment: If this is Python3, putting parentheses around your arguments to `print` should resolve that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26938835/2750877) answer, `print` is a function in Python 3, which means you need to wrap the arguments to print within parentheses.

So this should fix the error in your case:

```
print("employee / supervisor id :" ,k.get_id()," Date joined :" ,k.get_date())
```

Comment: So why not flag the post as a duplicate? Not that we have enough information to be sure that it is a Python 2 / 3 issue here.

Comment: bork thank you, putting parentheses around it did solve the problem. Thank You!