# How would I format a string with variables using the new line feature

Tags: python, string

I would like a string with var1 on the first line and var2 on second line. It would look like this printed:

Var1

Var2

would the code be

```
product = str(var1 /n + var2)
print(product)
```

?

Comment: But I mean come on, this takes 3secs to google and is not a suitable question for SO

Comment: Also see: [Printing variables in Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26938799/1164465)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways this can be done, but what you are suggesting will not work. Here are a few ways

```
print("%s\n%s" %(var1, var2))
print("{}\n{}".format(var1, var2))
print(f"{var1}\n{var2}") # python >= 3.6
```